# Set sps page width

Tags: sharepoint-server, page-layout

I want to set the sharepoint intranet homepage width.
If i view in 80% from IE or chrome all the content appears better n sharper. However, at 100% (nornal view) the content appears too large / big in size.

Therefore, want to set the same for all pages on my site.

Comment: Which SharePoint version are you using?

Comment: Is that works for you? or you are using different SharePoint version?

Comment: Have you tried below given solution?

Answer (score 0):

**For SharePoint 2010**

Please insert below given CSS code to your applied master page.

```
#s4-bodyContainer {
width: 950px !important;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

You can follow below article to fulfill your requirements.

[Creating a centered fixed width design in SharePoint 2010](http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2012/04/creating-centered-fixed-width-design-sharepoint-2010/)

**Note:-**

Please change the width as per your need in given CSS class.

Comment: thanks for the followup. I`ve tried on my SPS 2013 Intranet site, yes it changes the width of the homepage. On the other hand, the webpart alignment is impacted, though all are set based on CSS. Any suggestions.

Comment: @ahmed, Using Stylebot in Google Chrome, I tried setting the Width of the page to: 1560px and height: 850px. Also added overflow: scroll CSS code - div.col-lg-10.col-md-9.col-sm-12 { width: 1560px; height: 850px; overflow: scroll; } Still the web part alignment getting impacted, Example screenshot for better understanding - a) Home Pg appears in Full screen with width set to 1560px, imgur.com/gcoTsxY b) When, Home Pg appears in Full screen with width set to 1560px, but browser Is set to restore down mode . imgur.com/3F9vVHz

Comment: I Tried following the article and mapping a CSS file, that would allow to set the page width. But still the webpart gets disaligned the moment the screen resolution is lowered. 

Any other option?

Comment: You need to go with **%** inplace of **px** for width..

Comment: Mate changing to % doesnt makes any difference with webpart alignment

Comment: You need to make work by changing the webpart zone width in page layout which you are using. & above code will work fine.